# Adding a boolean to results, that is true if _id is in the results of another query of another collection

Tags: mongodb

CollectionB has a field (let's call it "otherId") that maps to `_id` fields on CollectionA.

I have a query that filters CollectionB to show specific documents, I want to, basically, return **all** documents from CollectionA, each having an additional boolean field, a flag that is `true` if the `_id` of that document is in the filtered results of the query of CollectionB.

I came up with this aggregation:

```
{
  from: "CollectionB",
  pipeline: [ 
    { 
      $match: { 
< Basically the filtering query goes here >
      },
    }
  ],
  as: "isOverThere"
}
```

This will add a `isOverThere` field to all results, that will always contain the filtered result set. Not quite what I need...

The filtering query is a geometry query - I don't think it's relevant to specify exactly what it is for this question (it works correctly and returns the right results).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Figured out a way. Left here for others + to see if anyone has comments/a better solution.

Aggregation stages:

1. `$lookup`:

```
 {
 from: "CollectionA",
 localField: "_id",
 foreignField: "otherId",
 pipeline: [
   {
     $match: {
       geometry: {
   << Geometry query here >>
       },
     },
   },
 ],
 as: "filtered",
}
```

2. `$addFields`

```
{
  isOverThere: {
    $toBool: {
      $ne: ["$filtered", []],
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing a dollar sign before `filtered` in the addFields stage. It's needed to indicate that you are referring to a field with that name rather than a static string